# How much energy is stored in the charge when electron and positron are created?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, charge

I had asked "The energy of electron formation becomes mass, charge, spin and momentum. How much becomes the charge? We know how much becomes mass: E = mc^2. What is the equation for the charge?". PabloG's astute analysis leads me to ask the question differently.
How much of the energy of the photon, which either becomes an electron-positron pair or is the result of their annihilation, is used to create the charge difference of the pair? Is it more then merely what is used to create the separation of the charged particles?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. If you are referencing another question, then you should provide a link to that question. However, I think is likely to get closed, if it is simply a duplicate of another question that you are asking in a different way. What is it you want to know that the answers to that other question don't address?

Comment: Do you mean this answer? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/289559/how-much-energy-is-stored-in-the-charge-on-each-electron/431111#431111

Comment: Welcome back! If you would like to merge your new account with [your old one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/134563/landis), you should use the [contact form](https://physics.stackexchange.com/contact).